# Concatenating #define in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I have something like:

```
#define BASE_FOLDER = "Resources"
#define PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME = "AppPreferences.txt"
#define SPLASH_FILE_NAME = "Splash.png"

#define PREFERENCE_PATH = ".\\" + BASE_FOLDER + "\\" + PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME
#define SPLASH_PATH = ".\\" + BASE_FOLDER + "\\" + SPLASH_FILE_NAME
```

and the compiler is throwing errors where PREFERENCE_PATH is used.

```
expecting primary expression before = token.
```

These all worked when I was doing

```
#define PREFERENCE_PATH = ".\\Resources\\AppPreferences.txt"
#define SPLASH_PATH = ".\\Resources\\Splash.png"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the equals symbol from the macro

Comment: Why are the equals signs there?

Comment: `#define PREFERENCE_PATH = ".\\Resources\\AppPreferences.txt"` This really worked?

Comment: @Falmarri, `const char * path PREFERENCE_PATH;` lol. I'm guessing it wasn't used.

Comment: @Falmarri = Yes the orignal way worked. I just asked the old developer of this code as it is his

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the equal signs. Preprocessor definitions don't use equal signs.

Then get rid of the pluses. String literals are concatenated when you put them side by side without a plus in between. Emphasis on **literals** because this is a compile-time feature that only works with double-quoted literals, as in `"foo" "bar"` → `"foobar"`. It doesn't work with variables.

```
#define BASE_FOLDER          "Resources"
#define PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME "AppPreferences.txt"
#define SPLASH_FILE_NAME     "Splash.png"

#define PREFERENCE_PATH ".\\" BASE_FOLDER "\\" PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME
#define SPLASH_PATH     ".\\" BASE_FOLDER "\\" SPLASH_FILE_NAME
```

Comment: I cannot believe I didnt see that.

Answer (score -2):

You can't concatenate strings (char* that is) in C++ like that...there is no `+` operator for them.